# jmockit errors while compiling androidplot from source

Tags: jmockit, androidplot

I am getting the following errors while compiling androidplot from source. I got the source on 29 July by doing 
git clone https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot.git

I compiled using

> mvn package -e

```
> Tests in error:   XYLegendWidgetTest.setUp:61 ExceptionInInitializer  
> SimpleXYSeriesTest.testPushPopStuff:93 » Runtime Stub!  
> XYPlotTest.setUp:58 NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class
> mockit.Mockit   XYPlotTest.setUp:58 NoClassDefFound Could not
> initialize class mockit.Mockit   XYPlotTest.setUp:58 NoClassDefFound
> Could not initialize class mockit.Mockit   XYPlotTest.setUp:58
> NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class mockit.Mockit  
> XYPlotTest.setUp:58 NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class
> mockit.Mockit   XYPlotTest.setUp:58 NoClassDefFound Could not
> initialize class mockit.Mockit   XYPlotTest.setUp:58 NoClassDefFound
> Could not initialize class mockit.Mockit   XYPlotTest.setUp:58
> NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class mockit.Mockit  
> XYPlotTest.setUp:58 NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class
> mockit.Mockit
> 
> 
> 
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Summary: [INFO] [INFO] AndroidPlot-Parent
> ................................. SUCCESS [  0.151 s] [INFO]
> AndroidPlot-Core ................................... FAILURE [  2.634
> s] [INFO] AndroidPlot-DemoApp ................................ SKIPPED
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 3.354 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2014-07-29T07:10:39-05:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 24M/348M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test
> (default-test) on project androidplot-core: There are test failures.
> [ERROR] [ERROR] Please refer to
> /home/binu/Development/Volta/androidplot/androidplot/AndroidPlot-Core/target/surefire-reports
> for the individual test results. [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
> execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test
> (default-test) on project androidplot-core: There are test failures.
> 
> Please refer to
> /home/binu/Development/Volta/androidplot/androidplot/AndroidPlot-Core/target/surefire-reports
> for the individual test results.
> >...at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
> >...at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
> >...at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
> >...at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
> >...at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
> >...at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
> >...at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
> >...at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
> >...at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
> >...at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
> >...at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
> >...at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
> >...at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >...at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >...at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >...at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
> >...at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
> >...at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
> >...at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
> >...at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are
> test failures.
> 
> Please refer to
> /home/binu/Development/Volta/androidplot/androidplot/AndroidPlot-Core/target/surefire-reports
> for the individual test results.
> >...at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:82)
> >...at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:195)
> >...at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:861)
> >...at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:729)
> >...at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
> >...at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
> >...... 19 more
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: What version of Maven are you running?  I'll do an apples to apples test to see if I can replicate the issue.